# How to intent from Activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

when user change display name, I want to intent come back ProfileFragment

FragmentProfile.java (Fragment) -> Edit Profile (Activity) -> save -> FragmentProfile.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChangeDisplayNameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

** MainActivity have slidebar

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data from activity to fragment and from fragment to activity, this is how to do it:

-from Activity to fragment

-- In activity

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) f.findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment);
fragment.setData(str);
```

-- In fragment

```
String fromActivity = "";
public void setData(String u) {
  fromActivity = u;
}
```

-from Fragment to Activity

--In Activity

```
 public void saveData (String u)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // do something 
}
```

-- In fragment

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).saveData(Res);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
ProfileFragment mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,
    mProfileFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(MyProfileFragment.class
    .getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: From where you want to jump to the Fragment class. Put this code in your activity to jump to Fragment and make sure your Activity class will extends FragmentActivity..